# How to write a script with multiple pings as condition to run a command?

Tags: bash, ping

I need to be sure that 2 machines are functional and 1 machine is sleeping to run my command. Here the logic:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping1=$(192.168.2.15)
ping2=$(192.168.2.15)
ping3=$(192.168.2.21)

if [ $ping1 = OK ] && [ $ping2 = OK ] && [ $ping3 = failure ]
then run_command
elif [ ping1 = OK ] && [ ping2 = OK ] && [ ping3 = OK ]
then echo 'machine 3 already running'
fi
```

I know the syntax is bad, because i don't know what do i have to write in the [ ]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell commands have a return status accessible by `$?`, ping will return `0` if it was successful, and something else instead, so we might as well test on that.

We can retrieve the status this way :

```
ping -c 1 192.168.2.15; ping1=$?
ping -c 1 192.168.2.17; ping2=$?
ping -c 1 192.168.2.21; ping3=$?
```

where `-c 1` will tell ping to only send one request.

Then we can test the values using numerical comparison :

```
if [ $ping1 -eq 0 ] && [ $ping2 -eq 0 ] && [ $ping3 -ne 0 ]
```

By the way, I would factor your tests into this form :

```
if ping1 && ping2 then
  if ping3 then

  else #(if ! ping3)

  fi
fi
```